# PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column "courseid" of relation "courses" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am doing Rails + PostgreSql app. I need to run sql dump on production env. I have courses table with courseID attribute. But when I run my sql I get this error:

```html
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "courseid" of relation "courses" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO courses (courseID, name, created_at, updated_at)...
```

Here is how my sql dump looks like:

```html
INSERT INTO course (courseID, name, created_at, updated_at) VALUES
('CSCI150', 'Fundamentals of Programming',
localtimestamp, localtimestamp ),
etc...;
```

Tried to put quotes (' ') around attributes, didn't help. Strange error. What might cause that?
EDIT: 
Here is what in my schema.rb

```html
  create_table "courses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "courseID"
    t.integer  "school_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

Comment: show your schema for table cources

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ, I edited my post

Comment: try to declare it as "course_id", if are relating this column to table

Comment: Hey you can replace column name with `""` like `"courseID"` because all identifiers which are not double-quoted are automatically coverted to lower case in PostgreSQL

Comment: try avoid uppercase in column names

Comment: if that is just id not as in terms of rails, use _no ending: `course_no`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All identifiers (including column names) that are not double-quoted are folded to lower case in PostgreSQL. Column names that were created with double-quotes and thereby retained upper-case letters (and/or other syntax violations) have to be double-quoted for the rest of their life. So, yes, PostgreSQL column names are case-sensitive

[Read it here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS)

Try changing `courseID` to lowercase or enclose it in doublequotes in the dump.